# GitLab CI build fails with error some local refs could not be updated

Tags: git, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have renamed multiple remote branches using the following command:

```
git push <remote> <remote>/<old_name>:refs/heads/<new_name> :<old_name>
```

Now the GitLab CI builds fail with the following error message:

```
gitlab-ci-multi-runner 1.0.4 (014aa8c)
Using Docker executor with image node:4.4.5 ...
Pulling docker image node:4.4.5 ...

Running on runner-705e3a48-project-15-concurrent-0 via d929b1291ac5...
Fetching changes...
HEAD is now at d4a38a6 DEV-3609 merging from as-37
error: cannot lock ref 'refs/remotes/origin/DEV-3425/feature(my-feature)tma': 'refs/remotes/origin/DEV-3425' exists; cannot create 'refs/remotes/origin/DEV-3425/feature(my-feature)tma'
From https://gitlab.myhost.com/my-company/my-project
 ! [new branch]      DEV-3425/feature(my-feature)tma -> origin/DEV-3425/feature(my-feature)tma  (unable to update local ref)
   5be484d..91bab37  v1.0(my-release-branch) -> origin/v1.0(my-release-branch)
error: some local refs could not be updated; try running
 'git remote prune origin' to remove any old, conflicting branches

ERROR: Build failed with: exit code 1
```

I have already run the command `git remote prune origin` but it didn’t help.

What can I do to fix the issue?

Comment: In the GitLab's project settings, try to set "git clone" instead of "git fetch".

Comment: @cascaval Good idea, and it worked. Strangely what didn’t work was setting the [git strategy](http://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/yaml/README.html#git-strategy) to _clone_ via the .gitlab_ci.yml. Do you know why? Anyway, if you post your comment as an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: Why the git strategy doesn't work? I don't know. It's listed as kind of experimental. Are you using GitLab 8.9? (I know, silly question but it has happened to me that I was trying to use something recently introduced while my GitLab installation was behind)

Comment: As for coming up with an answer - that one sentence is not worth as an answer. :-) Btw, you could probably also clean the build folder into which the runner fetches the code.

Comment: @cascaval We’re using GitLab Community Edition 8.6.4, maybe this version is really behind the docs. I still think the one sentence belongs in an answer since it helped me and might also help others. Plus you’d get some internet points : ]

Comment: @tmTM - Please add your comment as an answer. I nearly missed it! :)

Comment: I'm using `docker container prune` as a workaround. From: https://devops.stackexchange.com/a/10984

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In the GitLab's project settings, try to set "git clone" instead of "git fetch".

I believe that [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38351328/gitlab-ci-build-fails-with-error-some-local-refs-could-not-be-updated#comment64115848_38351328) should be the accepted answer!